# SMBD High CPU usage

Tags: networking, samba, smb

On a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 system, running a fresh Samba with default settings, I'm getting 100% on 1 core from Smb deamon (visible by running `top`)

- process is run by user, not root (even though it's started with `systemctl start smbd.service`)
- high usage disappears when adding `server max protocol=SMB2` to `/etc/smb.conf` (but SMB shares don't work with that setting)
- when putting actual load on the Samba shares, a second Smbd appears with a reasonable load

What's going on here? Why is there a second process running?

Comment: According to `smbstatus` the connection is made on SMB3_11.

Comment: that's on the host (the one with the CPU issue). I thought the output of `smbtools` was the negotiated connection.. no?

Comment: I can confirm: I restarted the connection after adding `vers=2.0` in `fstab` and now on the host it says SMB2_02 as output of `smbstatus`.

Comment: okay so it wasn't my idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears this was something temporary. I can't find documentation on it, but I think Ubuntu (the client) was indexing the files since they are mounted as `/home/user/Documents`. Anyhow, after a few hours the high CPU usage disappeared by itself.